# Node.js assert module: message parameter meaning

Tags: javascript, node.js

Reading [Node.js assert's module documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_value_message_assert_ok_value_message) I have been failing to understand what is the meaning of the `message` parameter and how should I use it.

If I write an assertion like:

```
assert(container.search('asd') === undefined, "Can't find [asd]");
```

When runnning the code, if it fails, I just get an exception at the assertion line, and can't see the message:

```
assert.js:86
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: false == true
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\tests\Container.js:70:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Comment: Have you tried using `assert.strictEqual(actual, expected[, message])` instead? I'm not sure it'll make a difference but it's worth a try

Answer (score 1):

The message argument simply defines what the error message will be if the test fails. This is common across most assertion libraries.

Example:

```
assert(false, 'hello world')
```

throws the error

```
AssertionError: hello world
```

Comment: Doesn't work like that for me with node v4.2.3 (the current LTS)

Comment: What output are you getting if you run `assert(false, 'hello world')` in the node repl? It should be something like this http://i.imgur.com/ElLmW0U.png. That was using v4.2.3